# C# Transfer not found in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code in a windows .Net project as a c# class file to script out all of the database objects out of a source SQL Server database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;  

namespace ScriptDatabaseTransferSMO
{
    class SMOObjects
    {

      public static void ScriptDatabase()
        { 
        Server srv;
        srv = new Server();
        //Reference the AdventureWorks2012 database   
        Database db;
        db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2012"];  
        //Create a new database that is to be destination database.   
        Database dbCopy;
        dbCopy = new Database(srv, "AdventureWorks2012Copy");
        dbCopy.Create();  
       //Define a Transfer object and set the required options and 
        properties.   
        Transfer xfr;
        xfr = new Transfer(db);
        xfr.CopyAllTables = true;  
        xfr.Options.WithDependencies = true;  
        xfr.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;  
        xfr.DestinationDatabase = "AdventureWorks2012Copy";  
        xfr.DestinationServer = srv.Name;  
        xfr.DestinationLoginSecure = true;  
        xfr.CopySchema = true;  
        //Script the transfer. Alternatively perform immediate data transfer   
        // with TransferData method.   
        xfr.ScriptTransfer();
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Transfer xfr; shows an error: The type or namespace 'Transfer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Reading about the Transfer object, it should be in the dll and referenced with the using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

I am still fairly new to C#, can anyone point out what I am missing to use this Transfer class? thanx

Comment: Right Click on your application, and add references, search for Microsoft.SqlServer.Management and add it. then save your settings.

Comment: Thanks iSR5, but I tried that and all it shows is Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.CollectorTasks and Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.  According to the online documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer(v=SQL.130).aspx  it should be in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need these additional components to install SMO objects

1. Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML)
2. Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
3. Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types

These components are part of the SQL Server feature pack, which is a collection of stand-alone installation packages that provide additional value for SQL Server. Make sure you select the feature pack that corresponds to your version of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @Akshara Thangam  I had to add the following  components from the SQL Server feature pack to get this to work:                                            
Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Shared Management Objects Filename: X86 and x64 Package (SharedManagementObjects.msi) Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server®   Filename: X86 and x64 Package (SQLSysClrTypes.msi)  Once these were loaded I had to add references for Microsoft.SQLServer.ConnectionInfo, Microsoft.SQLServer.Smo and Microsoft.SQLServer.SmoExtended.  Then it worked.